# Web Deployment Publish parameters.xml to match windows authentication providers

Tags: iis-7.5, web-deployment, webdeploy, publish-profiles

I have a Web Deployment publish profile in my visual studio project.
I have multiple environments, which in one I use NTLM provider and on the other I user Negotiate:Kerberos provider on the windows authentication mode.

My question is: How can I set the parameters.xml "match" value in order to set the right provider when using msdeploy.

The provider tag is as follows:

```
<add value="NTLM" />
```

Or instead:

```
<add value="Negotiate:Kerberos" />
```

Is it even possible to pull this of via parameters.xml only?
If not what is the right way of doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround.

At the parameters.xml I created a `<parameter>` element with the following:

```
<parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web\.config$" match="/configuration/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication/providers/add/@value" />
```

This `parameterEntry` will match the providers.

Afterwards, at the deploy time, the value that will be replacing the matched value in the `parameterEntry` will be: `Negotiate:Kerberos`.

In this way, I managed to replace the values. Currently it's kind of problematic to place multiple providers, but I think it can be accomplished with matchers and the parameters.xml by changing it a little bit.